# FTP performance with PHP and Symfony Finder

Tags: php, symfony, ftp, iterator

I am developing an application that needs to list and download a bunch of files from a remote FTP directory. For this I am using the Symfony Finder component, which is built on top of SPL iterators like RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

My problem is that the performance is absolutely abysmal. For example, the following code:

```
<?php

$finder = new \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
$finder->files()->in('ftp://user:password@example.org/')->name('*.tif');

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    var_dump($file->getPathname());
}
```

On some FTP services this gives me about one filename every 10-30 seconds!

I ran the code through XDebug Profiler and most time is spend in internal PHP functions like `php::RecursiveDirectoryIterator->hasChildren`, `php::FilterIterator->next` and `php::SplFileInfo->isDir`.

I also ran my script with Wireshark enabled because I suspected that maybe PHP is downloading the entire file just to list them, but that does not appear to be the case.

Does anyone know why the performance is so bad? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that PHP's `SplFileInfo` reconnects to the FTP server every time you call a method like `isFile()` or `isDir()` on it. These methods are used by Finder and that is what is causing the bad performance. Multiple FTP sessions are opened for every file in order to get all the file information.

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18923

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get full list of files, and filter it in your script.